# Ubuntu 23.04 fails to start, please see the error message in the picture, the computer will stop to work and only display that message

Tags: reboot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX8yh.jpg)

This is a photo of my screen whenever I push the power button to boot: